# Expect Script: Parse Specific Info From Cisco CLI

Tags: parsing, expect, cisco, command-line-interface

I'm new to Expect scripting, and trying to parse Cisco router ACL output.

I'm specifically trying to parse IP addresses between the first 2 remark lines.  Any help greatly appreciated.

---

Here's one of my random attempts.  It parses IP addresses from the ACL, but doesn't stop at the 2nd remark line:

```
send "show run | section ip access-list extended OUTSIDE\r\n"
set ip {}
    expect {
       "remark ##### DENIED HOSTS #####\r\n" {
          expect -re {(\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+)} {
            set ip "${ip}$expect_out(0,string)"
            puts $ip
            set ip {}
            exp_continue
            }
          }
    }
```

Not only does the script not stop at the 2nd remark line like I want it to, but it doesn't seem to have an exit point and waits for Expect to timeout.

Random sample ACL for reference:

```
ip access-list extended OUTSIDE
 remark ##### DENIED HOSTS #####
 deny   ip host 2.2.2.2 any
 deny   ip host 9.9.9.9 any
 deny   ip host 8.7.6.5 any
 deny   ip host 5.6.7.8 any
 deny   ip host 5.5.5.5 any
 deny   ip host 4.4.4.4 any
 deny   ip host 3.3.3.3 any
 remark ########################
 permit tcp any any eq 22
 deny   ip any any
 permit ip host 2.3.5.1 any
```

I basically want to parse addresses from 2.2.2.2 to 3.3.3.3, but then exit once the script reaches the 2nd remark line.

Comment: Please format your post. Reading an essay is just not fun here...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `exp_continue`, it is always better to add the case where we want to terminate from  expect. So that, if the exit case arrived, we can terminate from the expect. Else, obviously `timeout` will happen.

E.g.

```
expect{ 
    “p” {send “\r\r\r”; exp_continue} 
    “+” {incr foo; exp_continue} 
    “i” {puts "test"; exp_continue} 
    “quit” exit 
}
```

As you can see, if the word 'quit' comes, then it will be exited.

Lets come to your question. You need to exit from expect when the word
`'remark ########################`' arrives. But, if we code like,

```
expect {
   "remark ##### DENIED HOSTS #####\r\n" {
      expect {

            "remark ########################" {exit}
            -re {(\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+)} {
                                    set ip "${ip}$expect_out(0,string)"
                                    puts "-->$ip"
                                    set ip {}
                                    exp_continue
                    }
            }
    }
}
```

Program will terminate the `expect` while the ip parsing is in progress at the middle of anything.

Instead of doing this way, you can better get the whole output and try to parse it as a separate variable, to avoid overhead within expect.

```
send "show run | section ip access-list extended OUTSIDE\r\n"
expect {
    -re {deny\s+ip\s+host\s+(.*)remark} { puts "match found" } 
    timeout {puts "timeout happened"}
}
```

Now we have the match and it will be available in the variable `expect_out(1,string)`.

Then we can do regexp in the variable and parse the ip address.

```
puts [ regexp -inline -all {\d.\d.\d.\d} $expect_out(1,string) ]
```

You can try one more way as below. Instead of doing regular expression at the expect, you can simply get the whole output and then do the `regexp` as below.

```
send "sh run | section ip access-list extended OUTSIDE\r"
#Assuming your router's hostname is `Router`
expect "Router#"
#output will hold the command output.
set output  expect_out(buffer)
puts $output
set ip_list [regexp -inline -all {\d.\d.\d.\d} $output]
foreach ip $ip_list { 
    puts $ip
}
```

Comment: sorry...accidentally replied as an "edit" to your response somehow :-).    Listing here as well.  Don't see an option to delete the edit update I made.

Comment: Thanks, you are a mad genius :-).   

The only issues that I'm seeing are that it's printing the IP addresses twice for some reason, and it also printed 2.3.5.1, which was a "permit ip host" address listed after the 2nd remark line.   

Any ideas?  Also, any idea how to add a newline after each IP address it's printing out?  I tried adding  "\n"  in various places in the   puts  line, but no luck.

Here's the output I got using your updates:
         match found
    2.2.2.2 9.9.9.9 8.7.6.5 5.6.7.8 5.5.5.5 4.4.4.4 3.3.3.3 2.3.5.1 2.2.2.2 9.9.9.9 8.7.6.5 5.6.7.8 5.5.5.5 4.4.4.4 3.3.3.3

Comment: Can you try print the value of `expect_out(0,string)` and `expect_out(1,string)`?

Comment: You can do formatting in the comment section too. Click on the 'help' link available near the 'Add Comment' button.

Comment: Update...the last code you provided DOES work without printing the addresses twice.  It turns out I had 2 ACLs that both started with the name "OUTSIDE", so that's why I was seeing duplicate addresses!!!   Only issue is that ALL addresses are printed from the ACL, and not just the ones up to the 2nd ACL remark line.

Comment: I tried printing the value of both expect_out(0,string) and expect_out(1,string) earlier by the way...had the same exact results either way.

Answer (score 0):

why dont you use perl with Net::Telnet::Cisco ?

https://metacpan.org/pod/Net::Telnet::Cisco

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Dinesh!!!

Reposting the final working code (or a mix of Dinesh-provided code) here so it's not lost in all the text above (and so I can format more easily than in the comment section).

```
send "show run | section ip access-list extended OUTSIDE\n"

expect -re {remark(.*)remark}
set output $expect_out(buffer)
#puts $output
puts "\r"
set ip_list [regexp -inline -all {\d.\d.\d.\d} $output]
foreach ip $ip_list {
  puts $ip
}
```

I commented out the 1st puts line, but left it there to use when testing to see what's actually being stored in `$output`.

Here's the ACL that was parsed from the router CLI:

```
ip access-list extended OUTSIDE
 remark ##### DENIED HOSTS #####
 deny   ip host 2.2.2.2 any
 deny   ip host 9.9.9.9 any
 deny   ip host 8.7.6.5 any
 deny   ip host 5.6.7.8 any
 deny   ip host 5.5.5.5 any
 deny   ip host 4.4.4.4 any
 deny   ip host 3.3.3.3 any
 remark ########################
 permit tcp any any eq 22
 deny   ip host 82.28.82.28 any
 permit ip host 2.3.5.1 any
```

I know, it's a completely convoluted ACL, but it worked great for testing.

Here's Expect script output after parsing the ACL:

```
2.2.2.2
9.9.9.9
8.7.6.5
5.6.7.8
5.5.5.5
4.4.4.4
3.3.3.3
```

Any / all IP addresses after the 2nd ACL remark line are ignored as desired!

Thanks Dinesh!

Comment: Great Mr.`Expect`'s expert :)